# ImageSharp Watermark .NET6

Tags: imagesharp

I found few examples on how to add a Watermark on a ImageSharp Image, but I get this error:
`` SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing: Method not found: 'System.Span`1<SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.Rgba32> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Memory.Buffer2D`1.GetRowSpan(Int32)'. ``

My code:

```
outputImage.Mutate(ctx => ctx.ApplyScalingWaterMark(SystemFonts.CreateFont("Arial", 10), "TEXT", Color.WhiteSmoke, 24));

...

private static IImageProcessingContext ApplyScalingWaterMark(
        this IImageProcessingContext processingContext,
        Font font,
        string text,
        Color color,
        float padding
        )
    {
        return processingContext.ApplyScalingWaterMarkSimple(font, text, color, padding);
    }

private static IImageProcessingContext ApplyScalingWaterMarkSimple(this IImageProcessingContext processingContext,
        Font font,
        string text,
        Color color,
        float padding)
        {
    Size imgSize = processingContext.GetCurrentSize();

    // measure the text size
    FontRectangle size = TextMeasurer.Measure(text, new RendererOptions(font));
    
    //find out how much we need to scale the text to fill the space (up or down)
    float scalingFactor = Math.Min(imgSize.Width / size.Width, imgSize.Height / size.Height);

    //create a new font
    Font scaledFont = new Font(font, scalingFactor * font.Size);

    var center = new PointF(imgSize.Width / 2, imgSize.Height / 2);
    var textGraphicOptions = new DrawingOptions();
    return processingContext.DrawText(textGraphicOptions, text, scaledFont, color, center);
    }
```

I tried few more examples but with the same result. The official code is not up to date anymore.

PS: SixLabors.ImageSharp NuGet version 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work with these packages

```
  <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="3.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing" Version="1.0.0-beta15" />
  <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.Fonts" Version="1.0.0-beta19" />
```

Your code was giving a compiler error here:

```cs
    FontRectangle size = TextMeasurer.Measure(text, new RendererOptions(font));
```

I updated it like this:

```cs
    FontRectangle size = TextMeasurer.Measure(text, new TextOptions(font));
```

usings:

```cs
    using SixLabors.Fonts;
    using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Drawing.Processing;
```

Check it and let's see if it works for you as well.